# Самолетом или на самолете?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее говорить "лететь самолетом" или "лететь на самолете"? Мне кажется, что, если "самолетом", то "пользоваться", а не "лететь", тем не менее, сплошь и рядом говорят "лететь самолетом" или "добираться самолетом".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре сочетаемости нет сочетания лететь самолетом (только лететь на самолете). Может, виноват рекламный слоган времен СССР: "Летайте самолетами Аэрофлота"?